# Are there any password management tools which can be managed via the web

Tags: passwords, password-management, keepass

We currently use [keepass](http://keepass.info/) but we are looking for a web based password manager. Are there any known free / commercial tools.

Comment: Keepass has the ability to access password databases from FTP sites over the web, no additional software needed.  We use this to have a central database that can be accessed by multiple people at different physical locations.  Not sure if this would solve the problem you are looking to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a longtime user of [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) and highly recommend it.

Comment: does it work using a HTTP browser (FireFox or Chrome)

Comment: @Joshua yes it does.

Comment: Aphoria:  Even though this post is closed, please [review this meta post](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/47225) on how to recommend software/other products within Super User.

Answer (score 0):

[LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) is a good web-based password manager. It's free for the default feature set, and is currently only $12 per year (as of today) for "LastPass Premium".

One thing that is particularly nice about LastPass, is that it works across all major operating systems (and mobile operating systems, although they are not quite as useful as the desktop browser extensions).